# How to setup 'topics' for function getPastLogs ()?

Tags: events, nodejs, ethereumjs, logs, history

Sir,
I want to read the past event log by using `getPastLogs()`，but I got the whole log.I hope I can filter some log.
I find I can setup the `topics` in `getPastLogs()`,but it always fails. How should I setup the `topics` in `getPastLogs()`?

Below is my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
contract ReadLogPOC
{
    uint gi_sum;
    event adduintevent(uint indexed p_data,uint p_sum);    
    
    
    function adduint(uint p_1) external returns(uint){
        gi_sum = 10 + p_1;
        emit adduintevent(p_1,gi_sum);
        return gi_sum;
    }
    function getsum() external returns(uint){
        return gi_sum;
    }    
}
```

I use `Node.js` and following to get logs：

```
var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"p_1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"adduint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getsum","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"p_data","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"p_sum","type":"uint256"}],"name":"adduintevent","type":"event"}];
var address = "0x61fab6aa9f16369e8e051688ceca7e01a61b9780";
var readlogpocContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,'0x61fab6aa9f16369e8e051688ceca7e01a61b9780'); 

web3.eth.getPastLogs(
  {
    address: '0x61fab6aa9f16369e8e051688ceca7e01a61b9780',
    fromBlock: "0x1",
    toBlock: "latest"
      }
).then(console.log).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

If I run `readlogpoc.adduint.sendTransaction(8,{from: "0x3d626b8fae039078fe5c33964e035c5a9d47b2e9", gas:900000}` in `geth`, then I set topics like this：

```
web3.eth.getPastLogs(
  {
    address: '0x61fab6aa9f16369e8e051688ceca7e01a61b9780',
    fromBlock: "0x1",
    toBlock: "latest",
    topics:[web3.utils.sha3("adduintevent(uint,uint)"),web3.utils.sha3("0x8")]
      }
).then(console.log).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

The output is `[]`.

How should setup the `topics`?
My environment：
`Web3` version is `^1.0.0-beta.36`
`Node` version is `v10.5.0`
`geth` version is `Version: 1.8.11-stable`
Platform ：`Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS`

Thanks~~

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can specify the name of your event directly as follow :

```
  contractInstance.getPastEvents('adduintevent', {
                  filter: {yourIndexedParameter: _value},
                  fromBlock: 0,
                  toBlock: 'latest'
              }, (error, events) => { 
                  if (!error){
                   console.log(events)
               }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

the problems is in the line:

```
topics:[web3.utils.sha3("adduintevent(uint,uint)"),web3.utils.sha3("0x8")]
```

it should be:

```
topics:[web3.utils.sha3("adduintevent(uint256,uint256)")]
```

hope this helps

Comment: This topics can show all the adduintevent logs. If I call the function 'adduint' with parameter uint 8. How do I show only this event log ?

Comment: I do a test. If the topics is :[web3.utils.sha3("adduintevent(uint256,uint256)")],"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008"),the result is right.

Comment: How uint 8 convert to "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008" using Node.js?

Comment: You just need to convert the number 8 to hex and then lefpad it to complete a 32 bytes word. If this answer helped you to solve the problem, please accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Also note you will need to be running an archival node as GETH only keep world state of the last 1024 (in case of a chain-reorg) and prunes the rest of it unless you're node is running in archival mode (`--gcmode archive`).

Answer (score -1):

I got it!  The example is below,but the input parameter is uint 10：

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const ethereumUri = 'http://192.168.2.17:8545';
let web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(ethereumUri));

var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"p_1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"adduint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getsum","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"p_data","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"p_sum","type":"uint256"}],"name":"adduintevent","type":"event"}];
var address = "0x61fab6aa9f16369e8e051688ceca7e01a61b9780";
var readlogpocContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi,'0x61fab6aa9f16369e8e051688ceca7e01a61b9780');  //新版本C要大寫：new web3.eth.Contract

var a = 10
console.log(a); //output ：10
var b = web3.utils.toHex(a);  //output ：0xa
console.log(b); //output ：0xa
var c = web3.utils.padLeft(b, 64);
console.log(c);  //output ：0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
var d = web3.utils.toDecimal(c)
console.log(d); //output ：10

web3.eth.getPastLogs(
  {
    address: '0x61fab6aa9f16369e8e051688ceca7e01a61b9780',
    fromBlock: "0x1",
    toBlock: "latest",
    topics:[web3.utils.sha3("adduintevent(uint256,uint256)"),c]   // the second parameter is variable c
   }
).then(console.log).catch(e => console.log(e));
```